# Cordova inappbrowser does not play media or download .ics calendar file

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, mobile, inappbrowser

I am loading an external `website` which i have no control over, the download `buttons` or the links that are meant to open somewhere else, e.g .ics or.pdf files do not have any effect or action, like opening it on the `app` itself with a default `application`.
this is the code

```
onDeviceReady: function() {

    var openWindow = function() {
         var ref = cordova.InAppBrowser.open('https://www.example.com', '_blank', 'location=yes,zoom=no,toolbar=no,enableViewportScale=yes');
         ref.addEventListener('exit', function(event) { navigator.app.exitApp()
         navigator.notification.activityStart("", "loading");
    });

    var loadStop = function(event) {
        navigator.notification.activityStop();
        ref.removeEventListener('loadstop', loadStop);      
    };

    ref.addEventListener('loadstop', loadStop);         
};
```

Comment: Did you think on the permission of external storage, for writing and reading. This could be the problem, else there is no download possible.

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
i have addedd this

Comment: Thats a good start, but if you want to open files you need also READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

Comment: I have included both, the error i get when i use a phonegap chrome debugger, when a link with a pdf it shows : Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type application/pdf: "https://example.com/upload/documents/presentaties/example.pdf".

Comment: The problem is that chrome interpreted this as a document and try to render itself. For that problem is a plugin available: https://github.com/johnculviner/jquery.fileDownload

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I somehow found a way to work it out on android, in the plugin, inappbrowser.java, on this path: \platforms\android\app\src\main\java\org\apache\cordova\inappbrowser

on the  this method, i added more arguments to get .pdf and .ics files

```
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView webView, String url) {
    if (url.endsWith(".pdf")){
        try{
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse(url));
            intent.setPackage("com.android.chrome");                    
            cordova.getActivity().startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        }catch(android.content.ActivityNotFoundException e){
            LOG.e(LOG_TAG, "Error with " + url + ": " + e.toString());
        }
    } else if (url.contains("/icsdownload/")){
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse(url));
        cordova.getActivity().startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

i also specified which specific package to open with. 
i could invite assistance on the ios part